# Как правильно подключаться к MySQL и выбирать кодировку?

Tags: php, mysql

Наткнулся на 2 способа подключения к MySQL и возник вопрос: какой из них правильный (правильнее)?

Первый:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "bd");
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");
```

Второй:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "bd");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: @AntonKucenko чем же правИльнее?

Comment: @u_mulder ну ты же знаешь прекрасно :)

Comment: Только кодировка должна быть utf8mb4. Ну и как **на самом деле** [правильно подключаться к mysq через mysqi](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

Answer (score 1):

Два ваших примера это на самом деле просто два подхода при работе с mysqli - процедурный (первый, с использованием процедур или функций) и объектно-ориентированный (второй, с использованием объектов и их методов). Зачем так - кратко описано [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php). Практически для каждого метода в mysqli существуют оба варианта использования (процедурный/объектно-ориентированный), каждый из которых описан в руководстве.

Ни один из них не является "правильнее" чем другой. Это просто разные подходы. Какой из них использовать - решать вам. Единственно, что рекомендуется - использовать при разработке проекта один и тот же подход: если начали с объектно-ориентированного - используйте на проекте **везде**, не перескакивайте на процедурный и наоборот.